# I want to print the IMDB rating of a movie/series to the terminal after the completion of automation

Tags: html, css, selenium, web, web-crawler

I am using Google search for finding the element, as it seems easier to navigate than IMDB.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
print("This program finds the imdb rating of a movie or TV series!!!")

def get_results(search_term):
    url="https://www.google.com"
    browser=webdriver.Safari()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box= browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    links = browser.find_element_by_id("//div[@class = 'slp f']/text()")#this line is problematic, should i use xpath?how?
    print(links)

search_key=input("Enter the movie name : ")
get_results("what is the imdb rating of "+search_key)
```

and here is the error...

```
This program finds the imdb rating of a movie or TV series!!!
Enter the movie name : inception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web1.py", line 15, in <module>
    get_results("what is the imdb rating of "+search_key)
  File "web1.py", line 10, in get_results
    links = browser.find_element_by_id("//div[@class = 'slp f']/text()")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 353, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Please be specific. Thank you!

Comment: You may have to narrow it down to the part with the error so it is easier for people to assist you. As it is, there are references to line numbers and source files that may provide more context into what's going on. Provide the other relevant classes for a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Please fix up your indents for a well researched answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little bit changed your code and it works. Added explicit wait and changed selector.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


print("This program finds the imdb rating of a movie or TV series!!!")

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    browser = webdriver.Safari()
    browser.get(url)
    search_box= browser.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()
    rating = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]')))
    print(rating.text)
    links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3/a')
    first_link = links[0].get_attribute('href')
    print(first_link)
    browser.quit()

search_key=input("Enter the movie name : ")
get_results("what is the imdb rating of "+search_key)
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it works flawlessly. Can you please elaborate a little bit what is going on in the until(). Thanks again!

Comment: This waits up to 5 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 5 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.

Comment: I'm glad for you. Could you choose the correct answer, please? 
Also, you can read more about waits in Selenium here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Forgot to choose the correct answer. Mistake corrected.

Comment: I was actually struggling with navigation since last few days. Can you explain how do you navigate using XPath and other methods?

Comment: To find an element we need to use selectors. If presented id or name, you can find these elements by id or name. Also, you can find by css class and others. For special cases, when you don't have a unique selectors, you can write xpath selector. XPATH let you to be flexible and find your element without any other selectors. We need to use explicit waits as elements are not appeared at once on the page. It's hard to automate social networks or big sites as they always change css classes and DOM of the pages.

Comment: You are Welcome!

Comment: I am playing with another selenium program. I am trying to take the href from <a>, How can I do that using XPATH. I've applied what I've learned here, and I am able to navigate to elements, Now, I want to navigate between webpages. How can i do that?

Comment: Hi! You need just find your element that contains 'href' attribute and then get this attribute using `element.get_attribute('href')`.
Example:
    `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h3/a').get_attribute('href')`
    
I have added lines to my answer to get the first link. Try to run the code.
There, I'm getting all elements and choose the first one.